# Regex for time format

Tags: regex

Can anyone give me a regex for a time in the following format? I've tried a few things but no luck.

The format is for times like this:

```
07:00 AM
12:00 PM
```

It should not match

```
7:00
7:00 AM
```

The time always has the form `xx:xx [am|pm]`

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what does "no luck" mean? What tool/language/library are you using?

Comment: `(?i)(((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):(?:[0-5]\d)\s*[AP]M)\s+(?-1))`?

Comment: Try this... `\d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Initial Answer

### Brief

Since you haven't specified a language/regex flavour, I'll assume *anything goes*!

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3X9nLr/3)

```
(?i)((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d\s*[AP]M)\s+(?-1)
```

**Note:** You can add `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end of the string if this is the only content of the string. If this is the content of a larger string, I'd suggest wrapping the regex in word boundaries `\b` to ensure what precedes/follows the match is not a word character (`a-zA-Z0-9_`).

---

### Results

#### Input

```
07:00 AM 12:00 PM
7:00 7:00 AM
```

#### Output

**Note:** The output below only shows matches of input above

```
07:00 AM 12:00 PM
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?i)` Match the remainder of the pattern with the addition of the `i` flag
- `((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):(?:[0-5]\d)\s*[AP]M)` Capture the following into the 1st capture group

  - `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])` Match either of the following (any valid hour)

    - `0[1-9]` Match `0`, followed by a digit in the range of `1-9` (`01` to `09`)
    - `1[0-2]` Match `1`, followed by a digit in the range of `0-2` (`10` to `12`)
  - `:` Match the colon character literally
  - `[0-5]\d` Match a digit in the range of `0-5`, followed by any digit (minutes ranging from `00` to `59`)
  - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters (you can change this to `\h*` for horizontal spaces in PCRE regex or `[ \t]` for more general usage only accepting spaces or tabs)
  - `[AP]M` Matches either `AM` or `PM` (with the `i` modifier, this will also match any combinations including lowercase characters such as `am`, `Am`, `aM`)
- `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters (same rule can be applied to this as the previous `\s*`)
- `(?-1)` Recurse the 1st subpattern (ensures the second timestamp exists)

---

---

## Edit

### Brief

Seeing as how you've now edited your question to better show input/output expectations, I'll edit my answer. It's very similar to what I put above, just without the ending, so the explanation still explains this regex properly.

---

### Code

[See it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3X9nLr/4)

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d\s*[AP]M
```

**Note:** This uses the `i` modifier (or you can prepend `(?i)` to the regular expression to make it case insensitive)

---

### Results

#### Input

```
07:00 AM
12:00 PM
7:00
7:00 AM
```

#### Output

**Note:** The output below only shows matches of input above

```
07:00 AM
12:00 PM
```

Comment: I think the op is wanting to match the format of a single time, ie. `07:00 AM`..  And not the whole string `07:00 AM 12:00 PM`

Comment: @MElliott Thanks, I've changed my answer to include an edit that matches new input/output expectations.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

`\d{2}:\d{2}\s(?:AM|PM)`

It matches this time format: `hh:mm [AM|PM]`

But does not match: `h:mm` or `h:mm [AM|PM]`

Here's a regex example of the above:

https://regex101.com/r/IFsyH1/1

Note: If you don't want the [AM|PM] to be case sensitive, just add the `i` flag.

Comment: @melpomene I believe in vim, quantifiers and groups need to be escaped. ie. `\{2}` and `\(am|pm)`